# Inserting rows with inputs in a table dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have built a function using jQuery to insert into a table a new row including some inputs, like textboxes, checkboxes and one button.

This is the code I have:

```
$('#AddEntry').click(function () {
    var lastTrClass = $('tr:last').attr('class');

    var textBoxTitle = '<input id="titleid" type="text" value="" style="width: 100%; vertical-align: middle">';

    var textBoxStartDate = '<input id="StartDate" type="text" class="required DatePicker" value="" style="width: 100%; vertical-align: middle">';

    var checkBoxSync = '<input id="Sync" type="checkbox" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" value="true" style="vertical-align: middle">';

    var lastDate = '<input id="LastSyncDate" class="required DatePicker" type="text" value="" style="width: 100%; vertical-align: middle">';

    var buttonEdit = '<button id="btnEditar" class="EditButton icon_only text_only" style="vertical-align: middle;" type="button">Editar</button>';

    if (lastTrClass == 'gradeA odd') {
        $('#DataTable > tbody:last').append("<tr class='gradeA even'><td>#</td><td>" + textBoxTitle + "</td><td>" + textBoxStartDate + "</td><td>" + checkBoxSync + "</td><td>" + lastDate + "</td><td>" + buttonEdit + "</td></tr>");
    }
    else {
        $('#DataTable > tbody:last').append("<tr class='gradeA odd'><td>#</td><td>" + textBoxTitle + "</td><td>" + textBoxStartDate + "</td><td>" + checkBoxSync + "</td><td>" + lastDate + "</td><td>" + buttonEdit + "</td></tr>");
    }
})
```

As you can see in my code, I'm generating the inputs into a `var`, but my question is whether or not this is safe. Is my code vulnerable to a JS injection or something like that? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It's as safe as any other way of appending elements to the DOM.

Comment: the "var" in your code are only scoped in the function and are private.

Comment: yeah the "var" is scoped just in the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of this happens on the client so you're code should be fine. You may want to check out client templating for this sort of thing though - then you can scrap the vars altogether and editing the html will be more pleasurable. I use [jqote](http://aefxx.com/jquery-plugins/jqote/) when I need to render relatively complex stuff from javascript.

Comment: Very interesting @coalvilledave, checking jqote. Thanks